# Easier Add-in Distribution for Excel Add-ins?

Tags: excel, office365, ms-office, office-js

I need some logistics help, I think.  I'm creating an Excel Add-In and I'm finally at the point where I need to deploy it so our users can access it.  I developed it using the Yoeman/VS Code method, as I ran into some snags while developing on Visual Studio.

The add-in is really only going to be used by about 5 or 6 people (our auditors that go out to clients), and they may not have access to our network servers when they're out in the field.  We don't have Office 365  across the board (currently we have a variety of either Office 2016 or Office 2019 depending on when the user got their machine).

It's looking like most of the options that the documentation suggest would require a constant web access as well as a web server to host the code on.  Is there a way to make this process more portable?  Much like how in older Office programs, an add-in was just popped in and it worked?  Even with the sideloading and what have you, it looks like it requires you to have a local server running just to make it function

Comment: I believe Office.js requires, at minimum, for localhost to be running. VSTO is for offline add-ins. If you are committed to using Office.js offline, you can have a localhost instance launch upon Windows startup and configure as in this video: [Sideloading Video] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins). Also see: [Sideload Office Add-ins for testing from a network share] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=11&v=XXsAw2UUiQo&feature=emb_logo).

Comment: That'll work for network sharing but it doesn't solve the issue for when the auditors are out on location without an internet connection or can't connect to our VPN to our servers.  Ideally I want a solution that is self contained and on their machines.

Comment: If you watch the video, it will show you how to spoof the network share with a folder on the local drive. This removes the need for a network connection.

Comment: Ah, yep, I see that now.  I must have just breezed past that part when I watched it previously.  The audio is super quiet.  I appreciate the help, Joe.

Comment: Seems I spoke too soon.  The video neglects to mention how to change the manifest to properly use this setup, doesn't explain what all is needed for the users to have it running locally and what have you.  The only reason I went with Office.js as opposed to VSTO is because literally all the documentation on the Microsoft site suggest fervently that you should be using Office.js.  And I want to make sure this is relatively future proof so I don't have to deal with it until further down the line.  Should I just completely scrap this and go to VSTO?

Comment: Is the implication that I have to install node on all of our user's machines and have it load up a server instance at boot?

Comment: When I referred to localhost in my first comment, I was stating you would need a local web server instance. Apologies if that was not clear. If you want a solely offline add-in, go with VSTO (again, please see my first comment).